# ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 saving the document but can not ever open the document once saved (only some computer models)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently I have a document template with macros endabled .dotm. The macro has a commandbutton in there that triggers the SaveAs2 object twice formatted as below.

```
Public Sub FileSaveAs()
    Dim dlg As Dialog
    Dim strSaveFolder
    strSaveFolder = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath)
    Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 (ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & " UsersName" & " FORM234" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm ss AMPM") & ".docm")
End
```

Second Save as

```
Public Sub SuperSave()
    Dim dlg As Dialog
    Dim strSaveFolder
    strSaveFolder = "I:\Form Storage\CoCopy\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 (strSaveFolder & "UserName" & "Form234" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm ss AMPM") & ".docm")
End Sub
```

Now here is the interesting part that has me stumped now for about a week now. This code works but only on some computers. Older models it doesn't work on for some reason. It doesn't matter Windows 10 or Windows 7 or Version of Office itself. It doesn't work on computers that are older in models like a HP EliteDesk 1 or HP EliteDesk 2. The 1 won't work but 2 will.

I have never heard of the vba macro being affected by the model of the computer version of OS yes version of Word ofcourse but never version of model. I have googled left and right and went to documentation from 2010 (including microsoft's killing activex issue of 2014 which I already ruled out)

[This is how blank I mean doesn't even open the white page underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wac.png).

Any ideas? Or have you heard of some computer models not running vba code but having the same OS and same version of Office?

Comment: Well, I'd say the `\` backslash might be missing in the first version? Have you checked what entire string concatenation for that file name is returning? I don't know why newer machines would accept such a thing, perhaps because for some reason the default path is being specified...

Comment: Sorry I should have explained the first version difference. The first version selects the path above the folder for the user to give them a user copy and the second one is a hard string that sends a copy over to their co worker who will handle the form twice to look for errors the first person may have made.

Comment: But that doesn't confirm whether the string being passed to SaveAs2 is a valid path. I don't see a backslash anywhere.

Comment: I have confirmed it is a valid path. The object ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path produces a valid path to the next folder up in the VBA console example. C:\Macro Test\Form234\Form234.dotm the string for the path would be C:\Macro Test\Form234\

Comment: But I don't see any backslashes in the code posted in the question. There's none following Form234, for example. And I just checked: `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path` does *not* return a backslash at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin, I figured it out by chance were you trying to save a dotm as a docm. If the macro tries to save the dotm as a docm the formatting for the data is two separate instances. I followed through with this and noticed it in a test I ran on the document when right clicked and opened and got the same result try saving the template as a docm document instead this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yep this is what was causing the image noted I just tested and flipped testing to simulate the issue. Thank you very much Blake, I will mark the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Cindy, Justin is right it does yield a proper path and handles correctly in the VBA console without the slash. In the first sub he seems to only be after the path for the folder and is saving on the next parent folder outside of the folder containing the template macro. I have seen this work elsewhere why it is not working on specific models has me at a loss.

The second seems to target the location more specifically than the second which makes since if the folder is targeting a co-worker. I am currently trying to recreate the issue but having no luck your code works perfectly on my two systems I have running, both are rather new.

Comment: Yes it saves to the parent folder so they don't have a mess load of documents in their master template folder. Yes again to the target location but it is more of a notification that they have to sign for corrected information but we haven't made it to that point because after saving (noted in the image) it is like it doesn't render even the white background of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the wdsaveformat to match an extension type the formatting might be handled differently on newer models (unlikely but worth a shot)

Or rewrite the vba and document on the older afflicted models to see if they handle the setup and formatting differently

Comment: Tested a list from Microsoft Docs of all wdsaveFormats none worked with the docm extension and also rewrote the macro on the models that are giving the issue did not work either.